# RecycleView en fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, recyclerview, adapter

Tengo un `fragment` llamado `fragment_Perfil` este es su código.

```
public class fragment_Perfil extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView mrecyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mlayoutManager;

    ArrayList<String> listaDatos;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        extraer_Datos();

        listaDatos = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            listaDatos.add("Dato " + i + " ");
        }

        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(listaDatos);
        mrecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment__perfil, container, false);
        perfil_Nombre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.perfil_Nombre);
        //slider = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.slider);
        perfil_Puesto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.perfil_Puesto);
        perfil_Estado = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.perfil_Estado);
        perfil_Municipio = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.perfil_Municipio);
        perfil_Zona = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.perfil_Zona);
        mrecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.Multas);
        mrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        perfil_Foto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.perfil_Foto);
    
        return view;
    }
}
```

Este es el `adapter` de que implemento en el `fragment`

```
package mx.flexor.flexorpoint.flexorpoint.ui;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import mx.flexor.flexorpoint.flexorpoint.R;

public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolderDatos> {
    ArrayList<String> datos;

    public Adapter(ArrayList<String> datos) {
        this.datos = datos;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolderDatos onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.multas_generadas, null, false);
        return new ViewHolderDatos(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderDatos holderDatos, int i) {
        holderDatos.asignarDatos(datos.get(i));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return datos.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolderDatos extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView imulta;

        public ViewHolderDatos(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imulta = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iMulta);
        }

        public void asignarDatos(String Datos) {
            imulta.setText(Datos);
        }
    }
}
```

Pero al usarlo me lanza este error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference
        at mx.flexor.flexorpoint.flexorpoint.Fragments.fragment_Perfil.onCreate(fragment_Perfil.java:58)
```

Comment: Te esta daondo error al asignarle el adapter al ReciclerView, tu RV se llama ''multas'' verifica esto en el XML

Comment: No acabo de entender lo que me comentas, a que te refieres ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error es simple, estas asignando el `adapter` sin tener instanciado el `RecyclerView`, lo único que debes hacer es sacar el siguiente código del `onCreate()` y ponerlo en `onCreateView()`:

```
Adapter adapter = new Adapter(listaDatos);
mrecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Ambos métodos quedarían de la siguiente manera

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    extraer_Datos();

    listaDatos = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        listaDatos.add("Dato " + i + " ");
    }

    //DE ACA LO ELIMINE
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment__perfil, container, false);
    perfil_Nombre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.perfil_Nombre);
    //slider = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.slider);
    perfil_Puesto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.perfil_Puesto);
    perfil_Estado = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.perfil_Estado);
    perfil_Municipio = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.perfil_Municipio);
    perfil_Zona = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.perfil_Zona);
    mrecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.Multas);
    mrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

    //ACA LO AGREGE
    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(listaDatos);
    mrecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    //------
    perfil_Foto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.perfil_Foto);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: No merezco a esta comunidad ;n; me ayudan muchísimo, gracias. En cuanto pueda te marco como respuesta

Comment: De nada!, si la respesta te sirvio, acordate de marcarla como correcta! :D